# Is it possible to narrow the type of generic parameter T to avoid casting to unknown

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add type information to an array sorting function in TypeScript.

Here's the syntax I'm after:

```
interface Car {
    color: string;
    modelYear: number;
    createdDate: Date;
}

const cars: Car[] = [{
    color: 'red',
    modelYear: 2000,
    createdDate: new Date()
}];

sortArrayBy(cars, ['createdDate'], 1); // invalid syntax, date is not a string or number, this should not compile.
sortArrayBy(cars, ['color', 'modelYear'], 1); // valid syntax, this should compile
```

Original code

```
export type KeysOfType<T, KeyType> = { [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends KeyType ? k : never }[keyof T];

type StringOrNumber = string | number;

export function sortArrayBy<T, TY extends KeysOfType<T, StringOrNumber>>(
    arr: T[],
    properties: TY[],
    sortOrder: 1 | -1
): T[] {
    const copy = [...arr];

    const sortByProperty = (property: TY) => (a: T, b: T) => {
        const aVal = a[property] as StringOrNumber; // does not compile
        const aVal = a[property] as unknown as StringOrNumber; // compiles


    }
    return [];
}
```

The syntax works like I want, but I've had to resort to a cast to `as unknown` in the function to get the code to compile.

I'm wondering, is there a way to narrow the generic parameter `T` (or other ideas) so that I can remove the cast?

Without the cast, the full error reads

```
Conversion of type 'T[TY]' to type 'StringOrNumber' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'T[KeysOfType<T, StringOrNumber>]' is not comparable to type 'StringOrNumber'.
    Type 'T[T[keyof T] extends StringOrNumber ? keyof T : never]' is not comparable to type 'StringOrNumber'.
      Type 'T[keyof T]' is not comparable to type 'StringOrNumber'.
        Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not comparable to type 'StringOrNumber'.
          Type 'T[symbol]' is not comparable to type 'StringOrNumber'.
```

The error hints about converting to `unknown` first, which is why I did that, I'm just curious about other solutions.

I have a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDSxEGcDyAzAFWWAB4CAadTIlAPjgF44BvOAbQGs4BLAOzg6YIeOAQC6ALlGcxcUDGC8AJliqIaqAPwC4U3sABuwKHAC+nISPEBuAFChIsOHgCuvAMYxuEftywBlGCg+AHMACgMAQwAbF2A9FwBbACNjOAAfOCwg0IBKKSjY1D8snN4Qlls4argoYBgXKH4kFGE4QrjGBiYAcmzg8p67U1sW1ECBkJwoADkk1JMmftCMuF554zsAegAqW39oeEioKEjEOGTzxJdorzBo1DAoCBRYbmBVMO4RPG4obLgPg+cGOqGAAEcXDFcgA6OAAEQgwN4EHgiQgSm+52g3BCfBiIJOZ1sOy29nAh2cbk83n4WEOAEEiYgAEKIMiUAgATTkIAUylUGGw+A0HLgE1C0zmKWMtFoYSqNWOUCkBDYYnIiuqTxexi8H1VXPVmpqWUO0yUxikAEZVgBaa22fLSWTMLVwdw+AGesDnJhsGGB5ViOzuz28AH02BsgAKz1eSEYcDCOoTiENuUY9DCkVVlGSqszDHobtNpvDAMiADUCUxImxU3rELJIqoJeUpRsoHYyzUK-BkjXoknkg3402W22ylNZl3Q73qlsth6vUch0n643YM2Qao3BwUQB3fit8XTzsy7twJdwQ-QDhYfMueD6YAqOD7o-8dytmDu003v2Fzrkwo5bkgk4frwB4QMeu5npMF4LNY17LneUAPk+L7AG+e7QV+Hq-rY-41N8yZ+O24TVtCmalgupp1A0TQgkOMLRBAP4PAAwhAiRgKCYQAAYACTMIOMSmIJmY7GasAWpsJHVCM9FkV8ATTmE4nRLktGKWWjGNPwWlsRxMTADxfECSJzDUdEknSbJMDyd2enKQuBnMWEObrukmQAAyZnayZaRk-k6XAMlRk5UCWi5pqmPOfaro5ACi4B1FgWC0qoTDge8WAwokkRgGEIBZo5sbjtupU6T2SW+jCUVeZE+ZFiWelATEIQ4jAAAWiRJlFaVPB8WVejCdRKC47jAF5I0GJQ7iNFAbWVPRDH1IZyYgJQiCrfNpW7Zmvkesth1wHtdW9qYuRXfpm3MV1PX9TmrV3Tdd0ed+LyIMMxE3vCwDosRfAKFAeCRDNcBccca1JexKqlJMd3opa0RcsAxwJJed3uHUkQKEo8IE-ECIk39thAT+-xSDDUDqkmbB0dUnoI1IPSTT0Jo1KjwDo5jiMAEx+SL3Ms-jhPEwoejAIeZMKGEuS2KYIbEVFTKnKyiBhNTj7sD0eOY5LJM9BqcDWrdqE8LwhTcEoWSILwMCRDtcBKCTPCqCiRxIys0BrF2lB9SUWC9RANz297K58dwDwwrY6vMmyOvHHrbAGxACNc3APS8-zxym5QFsoTetv21gjvO67weqKH4fRPbnoxw8QA) setup with the problem.

Comment: Please include all code necessary to demonstrate your issue as plain text in the question post itself; an external link like a TS Playground is a great supplement, but it is doesn't take the place of having the [mre] in the question itself.

Comment: Once you do that: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/wRRe7w) is how I'd do it; does that address your issue, or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added the minimal code into the question. I guess your answer sort of answers the question, as it allows for the removal of the unknown casts. The drawback is that the func becomes very user unfriendly, as you will no longer get any IDE suggestions for what strings you're supposed to pass as sort properties. 

It also won't work if the array model contains any optional properties, but that's a bit out of scope of the question I guess. I did learn about the `PropertyKey` keyword though, thanks for that!

Comment: So then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq5oqm) work for your use cases?

Comment: It does, I added a Partial to support models with optional params in them. Post that up so I can accept answer, and thank you! `export function sortArrayBy<T extends Partial<Record<K, StringOrNumber>>, K extends KeysOfType<T, StringOrNumber>>(
    arr: T[],
    properties: K[],
    sortOrder: 1 | -1
): T[]`

Comment: I’ll write something up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the compiler isn't smart enough to see that `T[KeysOfType<T, V>]` must be assignable to `V` for generic `T`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728) for more information.

What you can do instead is to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the generic object type `T` to `Record<K, string | number>` as well as constraining the key type `K` to `KeysOfType<T, string | number>`.  (I'm calling the key type the more conventional `K` here instead of `TY`, if you don't mind.) In some sense this is a circular and redundant constraint, but the compiler is happy with it.  And when you have a type `T` constrained to `Record<K, V>`, the compiler *is* smart enough to see that `T[K]` is assignable to `V`:

```
export function sortArrayByExample<
    T extends Record<K, string | number>,
    K extends KeysOfType<T, string | number>
>(arr: T[], keys: K[]) {
    const sortByProperty = (property: K) => (a: T, b: T) => {
        const aVal: StringOrNumber = a[property]; // okay
        const bVal: StringOrNumber = b[property]; // okay    
    };
}
```

The `T extends Record<K, string | number>` is for the benefit of the compiler inside the implementation of the function, while `K extends KeysOfType<T, string | number>` is for the benefit of the caller so that they get both IntelliSense and useful error messages:

```
sortArrayByExample(cars, ['createdDate']); // error
// ---------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '"createdDate"' is not assignable to type 'KeysOfType<Car, string | number>'

sortArrayByExample(cars, ['color', 'modelYear']); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEV0wZwGUYpMUBzACgDcBDAGyWAC44UkBbAI2CjgB84+EmXIBKVnUbA8+ISIpwA3gCg46uFGAwkUXDACeYYBARwpTOAF4bcAOTDSFOwG4VAXxWHjcYk-IA8lAAcpw8fFby-gJsYbxuoJCwcN4yANLABvgBCAAqRsAAPLkANHAAagB81spwANoACni4ANaZpnC5ALqsuY1dcKAwwCgAJnLlcAD8cE2sKMDUvHDudW0GHd1uKiqJ0PDI6Fg4QvsAglBQtAYAQgYAoiC0HGD0RWoauYMgw2NyAErANDQUaFNJlRyiGLsbi8SolD7qNLfX7jOAZLI5fLGYoQhTkaFxKCVFSVSi0S69OpdMrrfCsNLUsTKRFwYEoYSnWB3BpQCDGWAGGqUMB8gWGBnMqzVcm9MpcXpS6qqDSqtk4Tm0coMVh+URBUKwiJwWh1UX83iGLouOAAeltcAgLWurNV7M5XG19F1+INRJqXDNYstBmtdodTuuqtZ7jcnh2u3A+0QqAw2Fw+HOl2ud0KrK+QxGaMBwKgoPBUShghh4XhrORhb+6My2TyBVxlcU1aJJLJrIpUCpNNZ5vFmGA9PR1IRqszsCCo14rAAjDEALTLlQSTrUllujXwYFgIWROoAOgvA+tO33HPgc5gPODguFo5DkusMtocrgCs6Sr3NV1HdeAtR1XxfRCf1IlNN9BWvIDgIPX8vR9fw-SNAMgwteDtkQvAzEoAg9QockvTEZkVXwjQtB0PQTS9M96AgNAGGAABhCAXgpYBKAAAwAEiUT0GHcPjmQAKi5GAF3iV0NE8fDMEI4j8UoET6AowDqM0bRdFwDSmJYtjOO4rR+KEsD6DEyTpNkqA3HwxTENo-S4EoMiGAEQQAAZmTXdyNO8uA-Nsh97MchS8I0EDpMeUUJ3wdM5EiOCsAnM8OFoMBKBAT9pKfHDDFyijIqQ48zwfDzaHlACqKA2KGHIaBMBgAALDgagfeKtHwJKNTPLRRiQNBeJFLRqDKNBdCgOr5KA1z6NysoDAAhLqGWuBVuC6bLk21ayrVdwxEO1VFtwJqWvajhyVqw7jsO871WPOMdntOAABFgA4CAdjIYYoAQWhRrgdiKW09VmMHTtyEOn7F3oABNYAKXmIlDrQLRaGGUYPuxlhPvx16VFi1ioEnMGoF3U96sh6BWDsIa7BnDR4eAJGUehgAmHzeZZ4CsZxvHhnmYAAHdCeGSgxA8a8VAfC4rluAxKDJ-AyjqOxMZRoX8bsGk4GXE7w2aKRMFGIQDBQGBaBAMpRnx2Q2AgUCYcdPga14Mp2oIIQ2ogJB6AtlAXfVF5MDeM95azJW7lVil1fqLWICh5n7DZjmKX1sojZtd6zYt-ArZtu2Uja338H9wOLeBcO3h2BXs2Vx5nleXi1Y1rXBeAXG9a6Y33t4PkoBUd613HifJ6n6fqgAP3nhfF4X0eHWxGQ7AAIm1-He+GDe7CdkPQL6zByBQWguDeFIIBSAp7AxVs18KSm8WibsjUqOwG5jnMHieF43jx3Jp3YEqcyh2AzsjLO-c84RmdAYIAA)